# Detect SIM change using PhoneGap in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, msisdn

I am working on a PhoneGap iOS application which needs to use the SIM or MSISDN for it certain functionality.  I want to know if there is any way I can get the certain information of the SIM like it's ID if not the mobile number or if I can know or niitfied if the SIM has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the MSISDN or IMSI.

You can get info about the current network provider, and you can get a token that identifies the user with the network provider. You can also get notifications when either changes.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/index.html for details

Comment: Thanks jcaron, but I understand that iOS does give me the ability to give notifications when either changes. However I need this capability using PhoneGap(Cordova) so not sure if there is any plugin or any API that could help me notify that the SIM has changed